# How to accept invites to Minecraft PE games

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How come when my friend gets an invite in Minecraft PE it asks him if he wants to join the game but when I get an invite in Minecraft PE it doesn't tell me anything? Also my friend has an android and I have an iPhone.